# Importing external stylesheets globally with CSS modules

Tags: sass, bulma, postcss, css-modules, parceljs

I'm struggling to add SASS with an external stylesheet ([Bulma](https://bulma.io/)) to my React application. So far I have set up [Parcel](https://parceljs.org/) with CSS modules via postcss. This is my `.postcssrc` config:

```
{
  "modules": true,
  "plugins": {
    "autoprefixer": {
      "grid": true
    },
    "postcss-modules": {
      "generateScopedName": "[name]_[local]_[hash:base64:5]"
    }
  }
}
```

I have installed `node-sass` and successfully added a `.scss` file to one of my components. External (Bulma) styles are added via `@import "~bulma/bulma";` and are correctly resolved.

Unfortunately, imported styles are not applied globally and instead the class names are modified similarly to local definitions, e.g.:

```css
/*! bulma.io v0.8.0 | MIT License | github.com/jgthms/bulma */
@-webkit-keyframes container_spinAround_28_Bz {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg); }
  to {
    transform: rotate(359deg); } }
@keyframes container_spinAround_28_Bz {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg); }
  to {
    transform: rotate(359deg); } }
```

Note the added prefixes and suffixes.

Ideally, I would like to import the stylesheet globally and do not modify their names. I'd like to continue using CSS modules and I think I also have to use SASS in order to globally modify Bulma stylesheet by overriding SASS variables.

Anyway, things I've tried so far:

- Using `postcss-nested` and wrapping the import with `:global` block:

```css
:global {
  @import "~bulma/bulma";
}
```

However, this throws an exception:

```
main.scss:5018:5: Missing whitespace before :global
```

- Creating a separate `scss` file included directly in HTML file via `<link>` rather than imported in a `jsx`/`tsx` file to avoid using CSS modules.

This seems to break Parcel entirely, as it fails to link correct files in the compiled HTML files, i.e. `<LONG-HASH>.css` instead of generated `main.<HASH>.css`.

- Using `postcss-import`.

Either my setup is incorrect or it has no effect on SASS files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define regular expressions to mark matched files as global stylesheets with the `globalModulePaths` setting.

```
    "postcss-modules": {
      "globalModulePaths": [
        ".*\\.global\\..*"
      ]
    }
```

The example above would mark all files with `.global.` in their name, e.g. `main.global.css`.

*Managed to figure it out while writing the question.*

Comment: Thanks, I tried a million other answers, but only yours worked!
I added it to a `.postcssrc.json` and I can confirm, it works that way too.

Comment: How are you importing the 'main.global.css' file?

like this:  import '../../main.global.css';

Comment: Thank you for this. I searched and tried a lot, I don't think this is possible in the postcss (i.e. without postcss-modules plugin). I could either use modules or use global (Plain CSS) but not both. Using this plugin I could do both.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that worked for me to load global CSS styles from rollup (when applying `preserveModules: true`) was using the '**rollup-plugin-styles**' plugin and the following configuration:

// rollup.config.js

```
   plugins: [
     styles({
        extensions: ['.css'],
        use: ['css'],
     }), …
  ]
```

// In the package.json you have to add the proper side effects

```
{
 "sideEffects": [
  "**/*.css",
  "**/*.css.js" //this one is very important too            
], 
 }
```

// MyComponent.tx

```
import '../styles/myGlobal.css';
```